# how can I object-orient a simple website copying app?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Getting straight to the point, I am new to object oriented programming, while learning Python, I wrote a simple procedural program that accepts a URL and fetch the data from the URL to a text file.

The code looks something like this,
Just ignore the varables, its made up!!

```
def open_URL(url):
    # try the URL
    # except errors

def fetch_raw_content(url):
    # fetch the raw content from web
    # return raw_content

def clean_up_raw(raw_content):
    # clean up html tags and stuff
    # format the raw content
    # return content

def write_to_file(filename, content):
    # create a file with filename
    # open the file
    # write the content
    # close the file


raw = fetch_raw_content(open(open_URL("somesite.com")))

content = clean_up_raw(raw)
write_to_file(content)
```

I'd like to know if I can do this is an object oriented way, since my exposure to the object oriented world is limited, If any one suggest me some way I can object-orient this program, thank you. :)

Comment: You don't need OOP here, just a single "entry point" function that takes `url` and `filename` and calls your other functions in turn.

Comment: FWIW, I suppose you are doing this as an exercise, but if you really need to do some serious web scraping in Python you may want to check out [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOP is a tool invented to fix code design problems. There are no problems with your design, and there's nothing to fix. OOP will only pay for itself if you really need the code to be more abstract and configurable. For example, at some later point, you might realize that your "content" can be obtained from different sources, not just URLs - files, databases etc. In that case you can "oopify" the reading part by creating an abstract class `Reader` and make specific "readers" for each type of source:

```
 class Reader:
     def read():
        # return the content

 class URLReader(Reader)...

 class FileReader(Reader)...

 class DatabaseReader(Reader)...
```

Similarly, if your "cleanup" process can be split in stages and you want to apply only some of them in a specific case, you can abstract it like this:

```
 class Action:
    def apply(content):
        # apply the action to the content

 class RemoveWhiteSpace(Action)...

 class RemoveFontTags(Action)...

 class OptimizeLineBreaks(Action)...

 class Sequence(Action)...
```

and then:

```
 content = Sequence(RemoveWhiteSpace(), OptimizeLineBreaks()).apply(content)
```

Yet again, these efforts only pay for itself if you actually need that much flexibility. In most cases, you can solve any problem in Python without using the `class` keyword.